# Javascript ES5 unshift / push alters original Array instead of internal Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i wrote a short Codepen where i tried to alter a temporary Array while keeping the original one, but both of my Arrays get altered.

Could someone explain me what the problem is?

```
var x = ["x"];
abc(x);

function abc(x){
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var y = x;
    y.unshift("y");
    console.log(y);
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
["y", "x"]
["y", "x"]
["y", "y", "x"]
["y", "y", "x"]
["y", "y", "y", "x"]
["y", "y", "y", "x"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript looks like if you use array.slice() you can properly copy an array, without the reference.  Worth a shot :)

Comment: `var y = x` is not copying the array. If you want to do a copy (shallow copy) then you need to use `.slice()`. Only then will y not reference x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no internal array. You have only one single array object in the memory. The `x` and `y` are only different variables which holds the same reference to the single array instance, because you have assign the value of `x` to the `y` which is a reference and that reference is just copied.

If you want to work with the copy of the array you can use `slice` function.

```js
var x = ["x"];
abc(x);

function abc(x) {

  var y = x.slice();

  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    y.unshift("y");
    console.log('Array y: ' + y);
    console.log('Array x: ' + x);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response and Thanks, this clears up the problem, i didnt know y was also just a reference :).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript handles objects by reference. So if you write `var y = x` it does not make a copy of your object but rather a copy of the reference. So when you update `y`, it updates `x` at the same time.

If you want to make a copy of your object, you can do the following:

```
var y = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))
```